# Prevent developers from sharing their API key

Tags: rest, api-key, data-protection

My company would like to make use of StackOverflow as a forum where developers can ask technical questions about our REST APIs. I found that there is a principle of "branded tags" (e.g. stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/your-company-name) that we could use to guide our customers to StackOverflow. From experience we know that a lot of developers publicly start sharing their private API keys (which are part of the URL by design) when they are posting questions. As API keys should be kept confidential, I would like to check how StackOverflow prevents developers from publicly sharing their API keys when posting a question. Alternatively, can we (as a company) do something to prevent this?

Many thanks!

Comment: This may sound trivial, but perhaps tell your developers to not share company secrets? It's actually part of most standard contracts.

Comment: If you know your developer's IP addresses, that would be another possible check. Or, authorize a given IP address for a given amount of time and after that, use standard 401 authentication with a shared key that changes daily or something. That will at least someone who's not a developer know that they're "hacking".

Comment: Before you start outsourcing parts of your support to SO make sure to know how this site works - since you posted this question here instead of meta it seems like you don't at this moment.

Comment: @piet.t I am indeed still learning to use and understand StackOverflow. I understood that meta was indeed the right place for my question but I couldn't post this question there with my new account (and reputation).